# awk -F not working

Tags: awk, text

When I do the following commands:

```
echo "1;2;3;4;5" > file.txt
```

Then:

```
awk -F; {print $1} file.txt
```

I am not getting the second element of file.txt.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Several things:

- the `;` is likely special to your shell so will need to be escaped in order to pass it as awk's `-F` argument
- similarly, `$1` will be interpreted by the shell unless quoted
- finally, `$1` will be the *first* element of `file.txt` not the second

So try

```
awk -F\; '{print $2}' file.txt
```

Comment: Correct form is awk -F\; "{print \$2}" file.txt

Comment: quoted also works, depends on what you find readable: `awk -F ";" ...` or `awk -F ';' ...`

Comment: @willy Your version in the comment wouldn't work, because $1inside double quotes would still be evaluated by the shell as variable, instead of by awk. You need single quotes around that, as seen in the answer, or escape the dollar sign with a backslash.